# Odd entry in WordPress 'Admin_Panel.php' file?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I just migrated a Wordpress install from one of my servers to another for a client (client's website which I set up and manage) and as a precautionary measure, I was perusing the 'Theme > Edit' listed files in the Wordpress Admin panel just to check for any links to the old server/domain and try to clean everything up.

When I got to the 'admin_panel.php' file, I found this entry at the very bottom of the file (it was the last entry):

`function ranking() {
  $pshow = "                                               <span style='display:none;'><a href='http://www.ellelive.com/'>Live sex</a> , <a href='http://www.2.livejasmin.com/listpage.php?psid=elenaa'>webcam sex</a> , <a href='http://www.2.livejasmin.com/listpage.php?tags=mature&psid=elenaa'>Mature Female</a> , <a href='http://www.2.livejasmin.com/freechat.php?random&psid=elenaa'>Livejasmin</a> , <a href='http://www.2.livejasmin.com/listpage.php?tags=girl&psid=elenaa'>Girl</a></span>";
  echo $pshow;
}`

Now, I'm not sure where the theme that I modified for the client came from, as he supplied it, but this is just... odd.

To note, the admin_panel.php file is for the backend theme settings section, so it isn't seen by the public. I also couldn't find anything in there that reflects this entry, but then again I'm not sure I would.

I'm not a coder, so I figured I would just see if anyone had any input on this. Is this likely something that was included by the theme coder? Or should I grill my client about where he sourced this theme and see if he got it from some shady website?

I'm just really unfamiliar with PHP, and while this looks harmless as far as site security is concerned, I figured I'd make sure.

I did remove the entry and everything seems fine, but better safe than sorry, right?

Thanks!

Comment: You did the right thing. But whats your programming related question? :)

Answer (score 2):

Whoever has made the template ( I presume "elenaa") chucked some hidden links in there to increase the google rankings of these websites. Replace the function with the following if your worried about it.

```
function ranking(){ return ''; }
```

If you just delete it you could get missing function errors.

Although the function is in the admin section is it possible the function could be called somewhere on the front end of the website?

Comment: I'm going through everything in-depth now and looking for anything out of place, as well as searching all the code for a few different terms/words, and I haven't found anything else as of yet. Also, I did go through the panel completely after clearing all cache and everything still seems to work as it should, and I haven't gotten any function errors as of yet, so hopefully I won't! :)

Comment: I think I spoke too soon. :( Now when trying to make changes in the Theme's 'admin panel', and I click 'Update', it says 'Settings saved!' but instantly reverts back. I found this out when I went to edit the text in the footer via the Theme's panel. When I click 'save' it just reverts back, and it looks like everything else does too. Any ideas as to why it would do this?

Comment: Ok, Update on that! I restored a copy of the original file, and instead of deleting the entire function, I just deleted all of the links from it, and viola, now my settings stick!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible issue: this is something that happens fairly frequently if you have the wrong permissions set on your files - this is especially true if it's at the very bottom of the file.

I've had spammers run scripts on my WP builds that will check to see if the page permissions are set incorrectly, and if they are, the script will write in some links off-site at the very end of the file. This is nice and effective because the spammer gets a Google rankings boost, and most people are never the wiser.

I'd keep an eye on your file permissions, and check back to see if these mysterious links have returned in a couple of months.